# Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication require

Tags: azure-devops

I'm getting this weird error in azure pipelines. We use a ACR to supply our base images and we connect to this using a service connection which works well most of the time. However occasionally we get an error:

> /usr/bin/docker pull ***/base-images/python:3.7-buster-vanilla
> Error response from daemon: Get https://***/v2/base-images/python/manifests/3.7-buster-vanilla: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.

There does not seem to be any clear explanation for this because when we perform a retry of the specific task this works fine.

We have no separate login to the acr and we only define the connection that needs to be used in the job itself:

```
    container:
      image: servers.azurecr.io/base-images/python:3.7-buster-vanilla
      endpoint: server-Service-Connection
```

I have been looking at the build logs but was not able to get any usefull information from there. If any additional information is needed i would of course be happy to supply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be running into a Docker Hub issue. We're experiencing this intermittently in our CI (not Azure) during regular pulls for python images.

From https://status.docker.com/pages/history/533c6539221ae15e3f000031

> February 3, 2021 5:21PM
> UTC[Investigating] A number of users may experience problems logging into Docker Hub.

Comment: Thanks for the information and apologies for late response

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this error using the Azure CLI `az acr login --name *registry-name*` Solution explained [here at Azure Registry troubleshooting docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli#individual-login-with-azure-ad)